# Linq OrderBy last n values

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say i have array of ints:

```
int[] values = new int[]{1,2,7,9,8,0};
```

How to OrderBy last 2 values?

```
int[] values = new int[]{1,2,7,9,0,8};
```

Comment: What do you mean by group? Like create a new array with the last 2 values?

Comment: Group, you mean swap? What has it to do with linq?

Comment: Sorry, i mean OrderBy.

Comment: What does it mean to order by last 2 values?

Comment: @M.Glita: Orber by or ordering the last two

Comment: Do you want just the last two items sorted -- or each pair of items sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0 };
// Array.Sort accepts index and length, so you can sort only part of array
Array.Sort(values, values.Length - 2, 2);
// results in {1, 2, 7, 9, 0, 8}
```

Comment: Can you do this with any other collections?

Comment: @Pete you can do it also with `List<int>` the same way: `list.Sort(list.Count - 2, 2, Comparer<int>.Default);`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Generic Enumerable extensions, I came up with this. *Don't think its the prettiest thing*. Evk's solution looks much cleaner.

```
values = values.TakeWhile((n, index) => index < values.Length -2)
        .Concat(
             values.SkipWhile((n, index) => index < values.Length - 2).OrderBy(value => value)
         ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int[] values = new int[]{1,2,7,9,8,0};
var temp = values. Length > 1 ? new int[2] { values[length -2],values[values. Length-1] } : new inte[];

Var templist = values.tolist();
IF (values.length >1)
{
templist.removeat(values. Length-1)
templist.removeat(values.length-1)
}
templist.addrange(temp.tolist().orderby(x=> x)) 
Values= templist. Toarray()
```

Im writing from my mobile sorry for the unformated text